# Jquery animate function doesn't work: Invalid keyframe value for property left

Tags: jquery-animate

[jquery file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/163RG.png)

above is my jquery code. I want every time I click the frog image, it will move to the left 50 pixels. but when I run the code, it keeps saying "Invalid keyframe value for property left: +=50px"
[google console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Rqs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example.

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
#clickme {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickme">Click me</div>
```